# Need the same sort of data fetched from databse in many ViewModels

Tags: entity-framework, mvvm, viewmodel, dry

I'm working on project in **WPF**, using local database (via *SQL Express*) and *Entity Framework* as a *ORM*.

I want to implement as many **ViewModels** as **View** classes. Kind of **1 to 1** relation, I've heard that's a good way to implement *MVVM* (if you don't agree, please share *why*). My vision of this is that every *ViewModel* serve its *View* (ie. sharing some data from database provided by *Model* layer).

So every *View* has its *ViewModel* which is kind of servant. ;)

During implementing this conception I came across the problem... Let's assume that at least 2 *ViewModels* want to get recent list of all the customers stored in database.

What would I do in this case? I would have to add this code to all of these *ViewModels* (against [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)):

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers;

private ObservableCollection<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
{
    var oc = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var query = from b in db.Customers
                    orderby b.Surname
                    select b;

        foreach (var customer in query)
        {
            oc.Add(customer);
        }
    }

    return oc;
}
```

or (alternatively) I would make some static `FooClass` with the same code I wrote above, but singed as **static**. It's not very clever because such a `FooClass` would be big pile of mess after some time.

I can't find any smarter solution. I'm sure you know how I should code it in clever way. So please help me. How should I provide the same functionality to many *ViewModels*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should abstract your data access in the consuming code into some layer that allows for your specific data access and/or indirection. A simple breakdown is to take the custom queries that you have, place them in an object and reference that object in your different viewmodels.

Below is an oversimplified example that leaves room for improvement but should give you a general idea, not sure how practical the viewmodel method is as below either but again providing an example for the stated code.

```
public class DataAccess {
  public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers() {
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var query = from b in db.Customers
                    orderby b.Surname
                    select b;

        return query.ToList();
    }
  }
}
```

...

```
private ObservableCollection<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
{
    var customers = new DataAccess().GetCustomers();
    return new ObservableCollection<Customer>(customers);
}
```

Along with this example you would probably want to split out `DataAccess` into aggregate root classes that deal with specific sets of data and can handle query criteria passed by the client, there are also other considerations such as not allowing the consumer to consume data entities but rather DTOs or domain objects and layers for specific business logic as well. The long and short of it is I wouldn't recommend accessing your EF data context directly from your viewmodels unless this is just toy/prototype code.

Comment: So I'll need to create new `DataAccess` object every time I'll open a new (sub)window in my application. Is it a good idea? Maybe static class would be better? I know that making classes and methods static is a clue that something is going wrong but in this case I'd say that calling `new DataAccess()` on each opened window is even worse.

Comment: @patryk.beza Correct I don't necessarily recommend creating a new object on each call although in all honesty as long as you properly dispose dependencies it is a very lightweight activity. When I said there is room for improvement for the example this is one of the considerations and I would imagine you would want to tailor for your specific use case. There are lots of options and all have their benefits and drawbacks. The primary point is to abstract your data access logic away from your viewmodels.